# Obtaining Dependency Graphs for Eclipse Projects Without the need of a full Build

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna, dependency-graph

I am currently working on a project within the Eclipse IDE, and I am exploring ways to generate dependency graphs for each project in my workspace without the necessity of building the entire workspace at the start (since the Dependency Graph is transient).

I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2. The projects in my workspace have various dependencies, and I want to visualize these dependencies without having to initiate a full build every time. For now a simple `System.out.println` could work for my problem.

The aim is to streamline the process and save time, especially when dealing with large projects.
It might also be acceptable to have the dependency graph from the previous build, but being transient, it is reset when the workspace is closed, so I searching for a **method to get the dependency without the need of a full build of the project.**

I am wondering if there is a method or a plugin available that allows me to extract the dependency graph for individual projects **without triggering a full workspace build at the beginning.**

**Question:**
Does anyone know of a workaround, commercial free plugin, or method that enables the extraction of dependency graphs for individual Eclipse projects without requiring a full workspace build at the start?

Comment: If there is such a plug-in it is not going to work on Luna which is 9 years and 25 releases old. But asking for recommendations is off-topic here.